# What is the proper syntax for aliasing a recursive CTE in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a PostgreSQL database of tasks and subtasks.  Here is my recursive CTE statement:

```
WITH RECURSIVE getchildren (childname, childid, parentid, parentname) AS (
    SELECT child.name,child.id,child.parent,parent.name
    FROM lists child, lists parent
    WHERE child.parent=parent.id AND parent.id=30
  UNION ALL
    SELECT l.name,l.id,l.parent,g.childname
    FROM lists l, getchildren g
    WHERE l.parent=g.childid
)
SELECT childid,childname,parentid,parentname
FROM getchildren;
```

Here is the output:

```
 childid |          childname          | parentid    | parentname
---------+-----------------------------+-------------+-----------------
      46 | Fix Escaped Chars           |          30 | List Program
      51 | Add Comments                |          30 | List Program
      47 | Rename Task                 |          30 | List Program
      36 | Dependencies                |          30 | List Program
      34 | Obfuscate ID                |          30 | List Program
      37 | Move Task                   |          36 | Dependencies
      82 | Second Order                |          36 | Dependencies
      38 | Reorder                     |          36 | Dependencies
      83 | Third Order                 |          82 | Second Order
```

I want to integrate an operation into the statement that removes results that are also parents: in other words, only display 'leaves' of the tree.

If the output of the latter query were a table, or if I spooled the results into a temporary table called 'temptab', I would want to run a query like this:

```
select childname from temptab where childname not in (select parentname from temptab);
```

To achieve results like this:

```
 childid |          childname          | parentid    | parentname
---------+-----------------------------+-------------+-----------------
      46 | Fix Escaped Chars           |          30 | List Program
      51 | Add Comments                |          30 | List Program
      47 | Rename Task                 |          30 | List Program
      34 | Obfuscate ID                |          30 | List Program
      37 | Move Task                   |          36 | Dependencies
      38 | Reorder                     |          36 | Dependencies
      83 | Third Order                 |          82 | Second Order
```

Can I alias the first recursive CTE query and combine these two queries into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le voila...

```
WITH RECURSIVE getchildren(childname,childid,parentid,parentname) AS (
    SELECT child.name,child.id,child.parent,parent.name 
    FROM lists child, lists parent 
    WHERE child.parent=parent.id AND parent.id=39 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT l.name,l.id,l.parent,g.childname 
    FROM lists l, getchildren g 
    WHERE l.parent=g.childid), 
  nonatomic AS (SELECT parentname FROM getchildren) 
SELECT childname 
  FROM getchildren 
  WHERE childname 
  NOT IN (SELECT * FROM nonatomic);
```

...using multiple WITHs.